# Disable an item using a dropkick

Tags: jquery, jquery-dropkick

Can someone help me with writing a sample code of how to disable an item in such a way so that the user cannot select it

I read the documentation from http://dropkickjs.com/docs/#Dropkick#disabled.

They only have for JavaScript and not for jQuery.

Any assistance is a great help.

Comment: Quickly skimmed over the docs, have you tried `$('#myelement').prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: why you don't want to use javascript?

Comment: @Alexan If the OP is using jQuery, then it makes sense to stick with that, rather than mixing native JS in to their script

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. I think its a valid question.

Comment: @CarlMarkham I tried '$('#myelement').prop('disabled', true);' I still was able to select the option. The option did not get disabled.

Comment: @CarlMarkham, because jQuery is just JavaScript library, I see nothing wrong to mix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.

Basically this is just a hack.

First when the user clicks on the dropdown list, the color of the option that you want to disable has to be grey so the user can know that the option is disabled.

Therefore, I implemented this jQuery:

```
   $(".dk_container").on("click", function () {
            $(this).find(".dk_options").find("li").each(function () {
                var value = $(this).find("a").attr("data-dk-dropdown-value");
                //The item you want to change the color
                if (value == "1") {
                    $(this).find("a").css("background", "grey");
                }
            });
        });
```

Once that is done, the next step is to disable that option when clicked. I implemented the following jQuery:

```
    $(".dk_container").find(".dk_options a").off("click");
            $(".dk_container").find(".dk_options a").on("click", function () {
                //The item you want to disable
               if ($(this).attr("data-dk-dropdown-value") == "1") { return false; }

        });
```